# What is the probability that the original sign was plus?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A slip of paper is given to A, who marks it with either a plus or a minus sign; the probability of his writing a plus is $\frac{1}{3}$. He then passes the slip to B, who may either leave it or change the sign before passing it on to C. Next C passes the slip to D after perhaps changing the sign. Finally, D passes it to an honest judge after perhaps changing the sign. The judge sees a plus
>   sign on the slip. It is known that B, C, and D each change the sign with probability $\frac{2}{3}$. What is the probability that A originally a plus?

This problem came in my test last week. This is definitely not a H.W problem.

I have no Idea how do I approach it. I think it has to do with conditional probability with,

$x:$ Event that A started with "+"
$y:$ Event that the slip ends with "+"

With the solution as the answer to,

$$\text{P}(x|y)$$

But I am not sure how do I calculate x and y.

There has to be even exchanges given A started with "+" for the slip to end with "+". This is how far I could get.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the final sign to be a plus there are few possible cases. If $A$ marked a plus, then there must be an even number of sign changes by $B,C$ and $D$ in order for the final sign to be unchanged - i.e. the sign is changed $0$ or $2$ times. If $A$ marked a minus then there must be an odd number of sign changes by $B,C$ and $D$ in order for the final sign to be changed - i.e. the sign is changed $1$ or $3$ times. So;
$$\begin{align}
P((A+)\cap (J+))
&=P(A+)\cdot P(0\text{ or }2\text{ sign changes})\\
&=\frac13\cdot\left(\left(\frac13\right)^3+\binom{3}{2}\left(\frac23\right)^2\left(\frac13\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{13}{81}\\
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
P((A-)\cap (J+))
&=P(A-)\cdot P(1\text{ or }3\text{ sign changes})\\
&=\frac23\cdot\left(\binom{3}{1}\left(\frac23\right)\left(\frac13\right)^2+\left(\frac23\right)^3\right)\\
&=\frac{28}{81}\\
\end{align}$$
By using Baye's theorem the required probability is
$$P(A+|J+)=\frac{P((A+)\cap (J+))}{P(J+)}=\frac{P((A+)\cap (J+))}{P((A+)\cap (J+))+P((A-)\cap (J+))}$$
$$\therefore P(A+|J+)=\frac{\frac{13}{81}}{\frac{13}{81}+\frac{28}{81}}=\frac{13}{41}$$